# Pull-up/ pull-down resistors in CMOS gates

Tags: cmos, pullup, pulldown

Can someone help me with understanding why the next two circuits have those outputs?
My initial schematic contains only one inverter, and the signal is 5V for output high state, and 0V for low.
Now, using one grounded resistor (that I think is pull-down resistor), my output values are 4V in HIGH, and 0V in LOW. Why does it work like that, and is it really a pull-down resistor as i think?

[image]

The second one is

[image]

and its output states are 5V for HIGH and 1V for LOW level. Why is it like that and is that a pull-up resistor?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where did you get the CD4049B model?

Comment: It's a library in LTSpice called CD4000.lib found here
http://www.amarketplaceofideas.com/adding-series-4000-cmos-library-to-ltspice.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first circuit has a pull-down resistor.  The high output voltage only reaches 4 volts due to the internal resistance of the output stage of the inverter and the current drawn by the pull-down resistor.

the second circuit has a pull-up resistor.  The low output voltage only goes down to 1 volt due to the internal resistance of the output stage of the inverter and the current drawn by the resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pull down and pull-up but not sure why the inverter needs them since the CD4049 is a push-pull output. Could just be for a safe power-off state.

The inverters have voltage droop when trying to sink or source too much current due to high output resistance.

Answer (score 0):

In first schematic, when output is HIGH, R1 and pmos pullup form a voltage divider. Increase R1 and you will see the output voltage increase.